# Deployment fails if DotNetCoreCLI and AzureWebApp reside in separate jobs in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been poking around in frustration to investigate why a build script works for deployment to site A but fails for site B. There's **absolutely zero** difference in the steps. Finally, I concluded that the devil is in the separation into several jobs. I need help understanding **why** it happens and **how** to enable the separation I desire.

The working version of those two steps is here.

```
- stage: stage_compounded
  displayName: "This is a working stage"
  jobs:
  - job: single_job_with_two_steps
    displayName: "This is both tasks in their common job"
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'SC-DEV'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        appName: 'app-dev'
        package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

The failing version is here. It burps on the second one claiming that there's no files aligning with the requested pattern (ZIP files, that is).

```
- stage: stage_separated
  displayName: "This is a failing stage"
  jobs:
  - job: first_job_with_one_step
    displayName: "This is the first task in its dedicated job"
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
  - job: second_job_with_one_step
    displayName: "This is the second task in its dedicated job"
    steps:
    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'SC-DEV'
        appType: 'webAppLinux'
        appName: 'app-dev'
        package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

I haven't been able to confirm nor refute the gut feeling I have that there's some artifact that is kept within a job but gets cleansed at the end of it. I haven't managed to find out much about that in the docs for [AzureWebApp@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-web-app-v1?view=azure-pipelines). There's [a mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-web-app-v1?view=azure-pipelines#error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern) of separate **stages** but in my case we have the same stage, just different jobs.

Nor have I seen anything useful at docs for [DotNetCoreCLI@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines). All references I've seen are to NuGet package repositories, which isn't relevant in this case.

I found the task [CopyPublishBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) but there's no references discussing that in a case like mine (it may be due to my exhaustion and frustration, though).

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on Azure Pipelines jobs? There is **no state** preserved across jobs -- each job is a completely separate working environment, as jobs are a unit of parallelism in Azure Pipelines.. You need to publish pipeline artifacts in the job that creates the artifacts, then download them in the job that uses them. Again, this is all thoroughly explained in the docs.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm in no way suggesting that it isn't explained. I just humbly point out that some people (including me) are too old/dense/confused to grasp that by reading extensive documentation. However, given the explanation of yours, I understand why placing those in separate jobs causes the effect observed. So, except putting a NuGet package out there to download from, there's no way to retain artifacts between jobs? Got it.

Comment: No, not a NuGet package, a *pipeline artifact*. It's not the same thing. I'll say it one more time: **look at the documentation**.

Comment: It seems like you're looking at the *task* documentation, which is great when you're trying to figure out how to use a specific task. But it's not going to help you with the basics of the pipeline platform, i.e. understanding what a "job" is and how jobs interact with each other, or how to share artifacts across jobs. I'm recommending that you review the *platform* [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: @DanielMann I've spent the weekend laborating with a bunch of stuff and decided to create a text file during a job and then have it available in another. After the pain of thousand cows' burping, I finally managed to grasp it. I was barking up the wrong tree. Maybe I'm not as bright, neither. But your hint on the difference of NuGet and the artifacts being downloaded set me on the right track. Thanks!